# RainTpl: how to get value of an array with key from loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

well, i assign this array (this array is for language) to tpl:

```
$arrayLang = array (
    "id" => "ID",
    "name" => "Nombre",
    "active" => "Activo"
);
$tpl->assign('LANG' => $arrayLang);
```

and i assign other array from a query to the database, this query fetch an array similar to:

```
$arrayQuery = array (
    0 => "id",
    1 => "name",
    2 => "active"
);

$tpl->assign('DATA' => $arrayQuery);
```

and i need to print the value from $arrayLang by key (this from $arrayQuery), so i use a loop:

```
<ul>
    {loop name="$DATA"}
        <li>{$LANG.$value}</li>
    {/loop}
</ul>
```

but this code print empty, i have tried with {$LANG[$value]} for same result. So, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in PHP while not in TPL. RainTpl didn't support this kind of call: `{$LANG.$value}`.

```
$arrayQuery = array (
    0 => "id",
    1 => "name",
    2 => "active"
);
foreach($arrayQuery as $key=>$val) $arrayQuery[$key] = $arrayLang[$val];
$tpl->assign('DATA' => $arrayQuery);
```

Comment: i have made this function:

`function key2val($key, $array) {
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        echo $array[$key];
    } else {
        echo $key;
    }
}`

and the use in tpl {function="ket2val($value, $LANG)"} ... for futures searchers

Answer (score 0):

First, wiki of raintpl here: https://github.com/rainphp/raintpl3/wiki/Documentation-for-web-designers

Secondly, use loop: {loop="$var"} $key and $value

The problem probably is bad loop.

Try change the loop.

Best regards!